# Issue with .\db\rep-cache.db file on SVNServer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am performing following steps on my SVN repository on SVN Server.

1. Taking the dump of my repository,
2. Make some changes on my repository,
3. Taking further incremental dumps,
4. Now taking hotcopy of repository,
5. Making my working repository crash,
6. Recovering from dump and incremental dump files.

Here I do comparison of two repositories using WinDiff: one taken in step-4(hotcopy) and other one after recovering in step-6 (using dump files).

I found out WinDiff shows **.\db\rep-cache.db is more recent in repository recovered in 
step-6.**

Can anybody tell me why here is difference in **.\db\rep-cache.db** and will it make any impact if I use hotcopy or dump repository?

Answer (score 2):

The `rep-cache.db` from step 6 has a more recent timestamp than the one from step 4 because you performed the recovery *after* you performed the hotcopy. The only situation where this would not be true is one wherein you own a highly modified DeLorean.

WinMerge can't do anything to compare those files other than look at sizes & timestamps because they're binary.

Comment: Wait a minute, Doc. Ah... Are you telling me that you built a time machine... out of a DeLorean?